# Switching between git branches in var/www/html

Tags: git, server, apache2

I have a git initialized in var/www/html folder on an Armbian Linux server that I log into via ssh. I have created several git branches for test purposes. In my web browser on my personal computer, how can I view the files (and file versions) that are not on the master branch?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-GitWeb , https://git.zx2c4.com/cgit/about/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you have is a non-bare repository on the Armbian Linux server, then you would need to:

- connect to it through SSH
- go to `/var/www/html` folder
- switch the branch currently checked out ([`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch))

See the result from your local computer.

Any other GitWeb-like setup would requite a [bare repository](https://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/), to be [shared on the server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server).